# Delphi - How do i find out what a component is doing 'behind the scenes'

Tags: delphi, custom-component

Im attempting to write a new component descendant from a common component (TDateTimePicker). My ultimate goal is to sub-class the TDateTimePicker so that when the user enters the component, the 'SelText' is set to a particular part of the DateTime.

At the moment, the behaviour of the TDateTimePicker is to focus the last selected text when it receives focus again. What i would like to acheive first, is to find out (look at) the code that actually is executed when the user focuses the TDateTimePicker.

I can see TDateTimePicker is a decendant of TCommonCalender which in turn is a decendant of TWinControl. But ive tried placing a breakpoint on procedures in TWinControl and they cannot be reached (which i guess is correct behaviour since a lot of components inherit from TWinControl).

So how do i find out what is happening when the user enters a TDateTimePicker? What code is run? Is it all hidden? I would hope this may shed some light on what i need to do to override the default bahaviour to accomplish my goal.

Comment: What do you mean by "cannot be reached"? The breakpoints don't break? Have you built your project with debug dcu's? You need to do that in order to be able to step into vcl code and/or have breakpoints in the vcl actually break.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`TDateTimePicker` is a wrapper around a Windows Standard Control. The Delphi wrapper simply sends messages to the Windows control, so there's not much Delphi code to read.

You'll have to treat the TDateTimePicker as a "black box". Whatever happens in there, it's an implementation detail you're not supposed to care about. In fact the implementation details for the Date Time Picker have changed, for example, with Windows 7!

Comment: So your saying this isnt possible? Put it in the too hard basket?

Comment: Not in the "too hard basket", in the "you'd need to be at Microsoft" basket. If you were at Microsoft, it might not be that hard!

Answer (score 3):

In Project|Options|Compiler check the 'Use debug DCUs' and the rebuild the application. Depending on the Delphi version this checkbox can be found in different places, this is for Delphi 2007.

Comment: Thanks solved my first problem, although didnt really help me much.